# Meaning of て　もかまいません

Tags: grammar

Does て　もかまいません　refer to may as in the possibility of (I might do ...) or I may (I've been allowed to )

Comment: Although this usually wouldn't be written with a space, if you *did* insert a space I'd put it after も, so it'd be like `～ても　かまいません`.

Answer (score 3):

It is roughly the same as 〜てもいい.  `かまいません` means "don't mind/care" (from かまう), so it is literally

> I don't mind (even) if you 〜　=　You can/may do 〜　=　It's OK (even) if you 〜

So it's more of an allowance than a possibility.